# Parallelizing Core Data import - Producer/Consumer

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, core-data

I'm looking to improve the performance of my Mac OS X app (a log file parser), and wouldn't mind seeking some guidance on techniques for parallelising the import process.  The basic gist of my app is that it gets fed a log file (could be hundreds of thousands lines long) that it reads, parses and stores into a Core Data database for subsequent filtering/analysis.

I am using multiple parent/child managed object contexts to ensure the importing occurs off the main thread, like so:

```
NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType (root MOC)
            ^^
NSMainQueueConcurrencyType    (UI MOC)
            ^^ 
NSConfinementConcurrencyType  (import MOC)
```

From a database perspective, this is working very well and I am now looking to improve the speed at which each line can be tokenized/parsed.  I have spent many, many hours in Instruments and am confident that the path for tokenizing/parsing an individual log line is quite well optimised.  However, iterating through each line is (currently) a sequential process... what I would like to do is read the lines in on one thread and then hand each line off to a pool of worker threads for processing (classic Producer/Consumer situation).

A couple of patterns that I can think of as candidates are:

- Create a pool of `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` MOCs, and then as I iterate through the lines, invoke my line parsing logic in `[moc performBlock:]`.  Seems fairly simple, but there will probably be some fun getting each block to call `[moc save:]` every few thousand records and also knowing when all the blocks have finally finished (I have some summary level info that needs to be collated once all rows have been imported).
- Create an `NSOperationQueue` and feed in an `NSOperation` for each line. Creating an `NSOperation` for **every** line seems a bit heavy-handed (bearing in mind there could be hundreds of thousands of lines in each log file).  Would also need a way to make sure each operation has a valid MOC (again, creating a new child MOC for **every** line seems like overkill)
- Use GCD.  Launching the operations within a GCD block using something like `dispatch_group_async` gives me a nice way of knowing when things finish up, however, again I still need a way of allocating out the MOCs and making sure the GCD blocks execute on the correct MOC thread.  Probably using `[moc performBlockAndWait:]` inside `dispatch_group_async` but I'm a bit wary of deadlocks mixing sync and async calls.

Any thoughts on the pitfalls/benefits of the various approaches?  Any approach that I have missed?  As I said earlier, it seems like a fairly classic Producer/Consumer problem (I am probably tending towards GCD as the solution), however, the additional wrinkle of the MOC management gives me pause for thought.

Anyone been down this path and have any thoughts they'd like to share?

Many thanks.
Craig

Comment: Before designing further, have you looked at dispatch_io, which is designed for these kinds of massive file processing problems? Once you see how dispatch_io does things, that will likely strongly influence your design.

Comment: There's a fairly nice intro to Dispatch I/O included in this talk from Dan Leehr. http://cocoaheads.tv/gcd-2-beyond-the-queue-by-dan-leehr/

Comment: To be honest, no, I hadn't considered dispatch_io.  I watched the video you mentioned (thanks for the pointer) and it reminded me, yet again, what an awesome piece of gear GCD is!!  As it turns out, I/O is not my bottleneck, but I can certainly see how dispatch_io would help if it was.  I am actually toying with shifting from my current I/O reading approach to using dispatch_io, but even so, I still need to fan out each line to a worker, and then eventually fan back in to complete the process.